# Start command cannot locate file from batch but can from Command Line

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a startup script to open a .pdf file. When I execute the command in cmd window, the .pdf will open just fine, but when I execute the command from a .bat file, it says "Windows cannot find 'myfilename.pdf'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."
The command I am using is

`start myfilename.pdf C:\Temp`

Not really sure what I should change other than perhaps insert change directory to C:\Temp before executing the start command?

Comment: Add some more information, for example why `C:\Temp` is involved.

Comment: I used C:\Temp because we want the file to be located somewhere that everyone will have. I am also running xcopy to add a file to C:\Temp, but I have noticed that some locations the window will prompt you to ask whether it is a File or a Directory that was specified, we do not want any user interaction. Is there a better way to get done what I want? Also seems that `start C:\Temp\myfilename.pdf` did what I was asking.

Comment: Okay, but what's the origin of that strange cmd syntax: `start <file> <path>` ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you are asking why I wrote it like that, I was using what looked correct to me. I sometimes don't understand commands the best because I am more networking than scripting or programming.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about the [`start` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297.aspx). So your question seems to become something more interesting...

Comment: What do you mean my question seems to become something more interesting? I'm curious and am always ready to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your command from the command line I assume you are in the same directory as the pdf file. That is why the file is found.
When you run a .bat file, the starting path is the path of the .bat file. If you have the .bat file in the same directory as the .pdf file, your command will work. If you have the .bat file in a different directory you can first change the current directory to the one that contains the .pdf file, or give the full path to the file like below:

```
start C:\LocationOfPdfFile\myfilename.pdf C:\Temp
```

Comment: Rather well explained. It may be also be important how the command prompt was opened...

Comment: I am actually in my user directory when I run it from the command line. This batch file stuff is beyond me sometimes.

Comment: Check if you can find in the PATH variable the folder your file is in. You can do that by
     -> echo %PATH% <-
This may return different results when ran from console and from .bat file. If you add your directory to the PATH variable permanently your code should work both from console and .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

If your batch file is not in the same directory as your file, it cannot be opened. If you specify the path it does not matter in what directory you are.

```
if exist C:\Temp\myfilename.pdf (
    rem file exist an is being opened
    start C:\Temp\myfilename.pdf
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```